# How to sort JSX elements from JSON values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### What I Want to Do:

I want to render a list of elements using `.map`, then sort by most recent on top. I've tried adding `.sort` and `.filter` before rendering the element, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've done some quick Google searches, but came across posts which don't seem relevant to what i'm trying to do. (or it's just me).

I want to sort by date, with the most recent on top.

### Render Component:

```js
import React from "react";
import TransactionEntry from "./TransactionEntry";

function Transactions({ transactionList }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-start justify-start w-full h-[520px] overflow-auto gap-3 no-scrollbar">
      {transactionList.map((transaction) => {
        return (
          <TransactionEntry
            id={transaction.id}
            retailer={transaction.retailer}
            category={transaction.category}
            price={transaction.price}
            dateAdded={transaction.dateAdded}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Transactions;
```

### Data Structure:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "ts001",
        "category": "Category",
        "retailer": "Retailer",
        "price": 1.99,
        "dateAdded": "04/02/01"
    },
    {
        "id": "ts002",
        "category": "Category",
        "retailer": "Retailer",
        "price": 13.99,
        "dateAdded": "04/02/04"
    },
    {
        "id": "ts003",
        "category": "Category",
        "retailer": "Retailer",
        "price": 119.99,
        "dateAdded": "04/02/09"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort before mapping in this way

```
{transactionList.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.dateAdded) - new Date(b.dateAdded)).map((transaction) => {
        return (
          <TransactionEntry
            id={transaction.id}
            retailer={transaction.retailer}
            category={transaction.category}
            price={transaction.price}
            dateAdded={transaction.dateAdded}
          />
        );
      })}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I swapped the `a.id` and `b.id` to `.dateAdded`, and it's not sorting.

Comment: You can not sort your dateAdded in this string form, you should convert it to number if you want to sort with days @Josh

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you're trying to tell me. Do you have a resource somewhere which will explain?

Comment: I updated my answer. If you want to sort in reverse way, you should change it from (a, b) => new Date(a.dateAdded) - new Date(b.dateAdded) to (a, b) => new Date(b.dateAdded) - new Date(a.dateAdded) @Josh

Comment: This makes sense to me now, thank you very much :)